# Transformation of connection coefficient

Tags: differential-geometry

My question is the following : I don't understand how we get the equation 7.29 (I agree with everything excepted this precise line).

I need to precise that I'm really a beginner in differential geometry, so my question is probably obvious...

The picture is taken from GEOMETRY, TOPOLOGY AND PHYSICS
SECOND EDITION
MIKIO NAKAHARA.

[image: proof of transformation of connection coefficient]

---

Indeed, I will have this equality :

$$ \widetilde{\Gamma}^{\gamma}_{\alpha \beta}\frac{\partial x^{\nu}}{\partial y^{\gamma}}e_{\nu}=(\frac{\partial ^2 x^{\nu}}{\partial y^{\alpha} \partial y^{\beta}}+\frac{\partial x^{\lambda}}{\partial y^{\alpha}}\frac{\partial x^{\mu}}{\partial y^{\beta}}\Gamma^{\nu}_{\lambda \mu})e_{\nu}$$

I identify the coefficient in front of the vectors, I get :

$$ \widetilde{\Gamma}^{\gamma}_{\alpha \beta}\frac{\partial x^{\nu}}{\partial y^{\gamma}}=(\frac{\partial ^2 x^{\nu}}{\partial y^{\alpha} \partial y^{\beta}}+\frac{\partial x^{\lambda}}{\partial y^{\alpha}}\frac{\partial x^{\mu}}{\partial y^{\beta}}\Gamma^{\nu}_{\lambda \mu})$$

But here I have a summation, I can't just put $\frac{\partial x^{\nu}}{\partial y^{\gamma}}$ on the other side like a simple coefficient ??

Comment: Multiply both sides by $\frac{\partial y^{\sigma}}{\partial x^{\nu}}$ and sum over $\nu$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can: continuing from where you left it, multiply that equality by $\dfrac {\partial y^\sigma} {\partial x ^\nu}$ and sum over $\nu$, to obtain

$$\widetilde{\Gamma}^{\gamma}_{\alpha \beta}\frac{\partial x^{\nu}}{\partial y^{\gamma}} \frac {\partial y^\sigma} {\partial x ^\nu} = \left( \frac{\partial ^2 x^{\nu}}{\partial y^{\alpha} \partial y^{\beta}}+\frac{\partial x^{\lambda}}{\partial y^{\alpha}}\frac{\partial x^{\mu}}{\partial y^{\beta}}\Gamma^{\nu}_{\lambda \mu} \right) \frac {\partial y^\sigma} {\partial x ^\nu} .$$

Remember that since the matrices $\dfrac {\partial y} {\partial x}$ and $\dfrac {\partial x} {\partial y}$ are inverse to each other, we have $\dfrac {\partial x^\nu} {\partial y ^\gamma} \dfrac {\partial y^\sigma} {\partial x ^\nu} = \delta ^\sigma _\gamma$ (Kronecker's symbol - summation over $\nu$ is again understood), which allows us to simplify the above as

$$\widetilde{\Gamma}^{\gamma}_{\alpha \beta} \delta ^\sigma _\gamma = \left( \frac{\partial ^2 x^{\nu}}{\partial y^{\alpha} \partial y^{\beta}}+\frac{\partial x^{\lambda}}{\partial y^{\alpha}}\frac{\partial x^{\mu}}{\partial y^{\beta}}\Gamma^{\nu}_{\lambda \mu} \right) \dfrac {\partial y^\sigma} {\partial x ^\nu} ,$$

and the LHS is obviously $\widetilde \Gamma ^\sigma _{\alpha \beta}$.

Comment: That was the answer I was looking for. Thank you